# How does Angular know if a promise is fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been reading about Angular promises to fetch data from a web service, one thing that caught my attention is that Angular for some reason knows if the "request" was fulfilled or rejected, how does Angular know that? Does it check the response status code? Can you redefine those rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct!

The HttpProvider, which is used by $http and $resource, for example, defines a successful response as an http response code between 200 and 299, inclusively.

You can change this behavior by supplying your own HttpProvider.  In addition, services which use the HttpProvider might override this response and substitute more appropriate failure/success conditions.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer as he provided the exact answers to both of my questions.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) is an awesome description of Promises in AngularJS. It helped me more fully grasp what was going on behind the scenes.

> We've already stated the logic, the father asks the son to get the
>   weather forecast, and as the son can't tell him immediately, and the
>   father has other things to do while he waits, the son makes a promise
>   he shall return with the weather. When the dad has the forecast, he'll
>   either pack up the boat, or stay inside. The important thing to note
>   here, is the son's trip up the hill shouldn't 'block' the dad from
>   doing anything, so this is why the situation is perfect for the
>   creation of a promise, which can be resolved (fulfilled or rejected)
>   later on.
>
> Using Angular's then() function we can specify what the Dad needs to
>   do in the event of each outcome. The then() function accepts 2
>   functions as parameters: a function to be executed when the promise is
>   fulfilled, and a function to be executed when the promise is rejected.
>
> ```
> // function somewhere in father-controller.js
> var makePromiseWithSon = function() {
> // This service's function returns a promise, but we'll deal with that shortly
> SonService.getWeather()
>     // then() called when son gets back
>     .then(function(data) {
>         // promise fulfilled
>         if (data.forecast==='good') {
>             prepareFishingTrip();
>         } else {
>             prepareSundayRoastDinner();
>         }
>     }, function(error) {
>         // promise rejected, could log the error with: console.log('error', error);
>         prepareSundayRoastDinner();
>     });
> };
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Grant, the post is awesome, however I understand the logic behind "promises", but I didn't understand was how Angular decided whether a promise was "fulfilled" or "rejected". The code you share is really useful as a second step, where you can decide what to do after you know the result of the promise.

Comment: @user1336321, I actually posted that and Grant added the details. Sorry about that, it didn't really answer your question. You were basically looking to understand the logic behind deciding what a successful response is versus a "failure". Interesting topic and Michael did a nice job explaining it a little further above.